# How can i view my zip files i uploaded on amazon as3 on chrome?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, articulate-storyline

I uploaded some scorm files(articulate storyline files "HTML, js, etc files") on my amazon as3 account the files are in zip format when I upload the zip folder and share the link of the object I only get a download option is there any way that whenever I share my object link and someone other clicks on it he/she see the content on the browser rather than seeing download option?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way, unless you are going to implement it yourself on your website or application.